# overlay image with a spinner

Tags: jquery, spinner

I need to overlay a spinner image over an existing image till the new image is generated & replaces the old one.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".deleteWord").live("click", function(event)
    {
        $("#Image").attr("src","").
        $("#Image").attr("src","images/spinner.gif");
        $("#Image").attr("src","RegenerateImage?para="+param);


    });
});
```

This is what I am currently doing. But this just removes the existing image, places the spinner, regenerates the image  & replaces the spinner.

Comment: have you tried what I have suggested?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Butcher. I get the following error:$("#HiddenImage").src is not a function

Comment: sorry change that to $("#HiddenImage").attr("src","RegenerateImage?para="+param");

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because that is what you are telling it to do :) What you need to do is hook up an onload even on the image.

There are many options to achieve this. One of them is to have an image with style="display:none;" on the page and to change that images' `"src"`. When that image loads change your target images `"src"`. Because the browser has already loaded the image it will just appear.

```
<img id="HiddenImage" src="" style="display:none;" />

$(".deleteWord").live("click", function(event)
    {
        $("#Image").attr("src","images/spinner.gif");
        $("#HiddenImage").attr("src","RegenerateImage?para="+param");
        $("#HiddenImage").load(function(){
             $("#Image").attr("src","RegenerateImage?para="+param");
        });        
    });
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, but that only kept showing the spinner image, with the new image not being generated. I used firebug to debug & noticed that it does not enter the load function. Here is the code

Comment: that HTML has errors. maybe that's why? <img id="HiddenImage" src="" style="display:none;" /  should be <img id="HiddenImage" src="" style="display:none;" />

Comment: HTML error was an typo while writing it here. I was rather missing the src parameter in attr method. I corrected that to $("#HiddenImage").attr("src","RegenerateImage?para="+param"); Now the spinner appears, but it does not overlay the previous image

Comment: put an alert inside the load function? Does it get there?

Comment: also are you sure that "param" exists?

Comment: yes, The code is reaching inside the load function. Also the param is fine because RegenerateImage correctly generates the new image

Comment: As the spinner image is quite small compared to other images. It is always top left aligned. How can we place spinner right in the center?

Comment: give the div text-align:center; and line-height equal to the height of the biggest image. Is the image still not changing though?

Comment: Thanks for the css help. Yes, the new generated image is displayed after the load function is called and the spinner disappears. But for some reason its not overlaying. I would love to love to overlay the spinner gif over my image

Comment: ok so you mean overlay the spinner on the image then when its loaded change the image?

Comment: that's a different story :) or i misread your question haha! :) Ok all you have to do is instead of changing the image src to the spinner, change the divs background to the spinner. eg $("div").css("background","url('images/spinner.gif') no-repeat center center"); Then on the callback after setting the new image url set the div's background to empty. $("div").css("background","none");

Comment: Yup. I was indeed looking for overlaying the spinner image over the previous image till the new images loads :)

Comment: This is what I have now based upon your suggestion <div id="image">
  <img id="wordCloudImage" src="images/output.png"></img>
  <img id="HiddenImage" src="" style="display:none;" />
</div>

Comment: $("image").css("background","url('..images/spinner.gif') no-repeat center center");
$("#HiddenImage").attr("src","RegenerateCloud?para="+param");
$("#HiddenImage").load(function(){
$("#wordCloudImage").attr("src","RegenerateCloud?para="+param");
 });
$("image").css("background","none");

Comment: Is this correct? as I dont see the spinner image now. Also do we still need to hiddenimage?

Comment: $("image") needs to be $("#image")

Comment: Oh you are right!. I replaced that, but I dont see the spinner image. I just see the old image getting replaced with the new one.

Comment: you must give the div id="image" a width and a height. And also give <img id="wordCloudImage" /> a z-index of -2. <img id="wordCloudImage" style='z-index:-2;' />